# how putting a "null position" in a taxonomy dropdown selector

Tags: custom-taxonomy

what have I to add to this code to have a "null position" or "no selection"? At the moment even if I dont choose a value, after I press the edit button, the system gets the default position value:

```
function custom_meta_box_markup( $post ) {
$post_id = $post->ID;

// tax_input[numero_ospiti] is an array,
// but managed as a single value.
$is_single_value = true;

// Retrieve the term name that was saved to the database.
$selected_term_name = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'tax_input[numero_ospiti]', $is_single_value );
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'numero_ospiti',
    'fields'   => 'id=>name',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'number'   => 0
) );

$flipped_terms = array_flip( $terms );
if ( isset( $flipped_terms[ $selected_term_name ] ) ) {
    $selected_term_id = $flipped_terms[ $selected_term_name ];
} else {
    $selected_term_id = 0;
}

$set_referer_field = true;
$echo_html = false;
$wp_nonce_html = wp_nonce_field(
    basename( __FILE__ ),
    'meta-box-nonce',
    $set_referer_field,
    $echo_html
);

$args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'numero_ospiti',
    'selected'   => $selected_term_id,
    'name'       => 'tax_input[numero_ospiti]',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'echo'       => false
);
$dropdown_cat_html = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );

$html = <<<EOHTML
<div>
    $wp_nonce_html
    <label for="meta-box-ospiti">N.ospiti</label>
    $dropdown_cat_html
</div>
EOHTML;

echo $html;
}

function add_custom_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'demo-meta-box',          // Unique ID.
        'Ospiti',                 // Meta box title.
        'custom_meta_box_markup', // Content callback, must be of type callable.
        'post',                   // Screen type.
        'side'                    // Context: where meta box should display in the screen.
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box' );
```

Comment: this should be documented in the 2nd and 3rd parameters of https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/ on the official developer docs site

Comment: if I use `code` 'show_option_none'  => '',
        'option_none_value' => '',  nothing happens

Comment: @fuxia I used 'show_option_none' => '00' and now there is a no option position, but how can I make the no option position an empty space?